# Ramsey theory in infinite-dimensional projective spaces

Tags: co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field and $k$ be a positive integer. If we colour each point of the infinite-dimensional projective space $\mathbb{F}_q \mathbb{P}^{\infty}$ with one of $k$ colours, can we necessarily find an infinite-dimensional monochromatic projective subspace?

---

There are a couple of observations that hint that the answer is 'yes':

**Observation 1:** The statement for $\mathbb{F}_2$ is true, and is equivalent to Hindman's theorem. The reason for asking this question is that it would provide an interesting generalisation of Hindman's theorem.

**Observation 2:** If we weaken the problem to finding an $n$-dimensional monochromatic projective subspace (where $n$ is finite), the statement is also true (and follows, for example, from the 'Vector Space Ramsey Theorem' in the paper *Ramsey's Theorem for Spaces* by Joel H. Spencer).

Comment: "infinite-dimensional" means (infinite countable)-dimensional? it was proved some time ago that there are several infinite cardinals :)

Comment: Yes: for concreteness, define $\mathbb{F}_q \mathbb{P}^{\infty}$ to be the union of the sequence $\mathbb{F}_q \mathbb{P}^1 \subseteq \mathbb{F}_q \mathbb{P}^2 \subseteq \mathbb{F}_q \mathbb{P}^3 \subseteq \cdots$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further investigation, it appears that disappointingly the answer is 'no', and a proof appears in Lemma 2.4 of *Partition Theorems for Subspaces of Vector Spaces* (Cates and Hindman, 1975).